# MongoDB - Execute stored function from Node without eval

Tags: node.js, mongodb, eval, stored-functions

I stored a function inside `db.system.js`:

```
function(ticker) {
    var rtn = [], last = undefined;

    db[ticker].find({}).sort({_id: 1}).forEach((element) => {
        if(last != undefined) {
            if(element._id - last._id > 60*1000) {
                for(let j=1;j<(element._id-last._id)/(60*1000);j++) {
                    rtn.push(last._id+(60*1000)*j);
                }
            }
        }

        last = element;
    });

    return rtn;
}
```

Now I would like to retrieve the data returned by such function with Node, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do it since I'm using Mongo v4.4.2 and `db.eval` has been removed. All the other questions I checked talked about that method, so I'm clueless. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}, function(err, db) {
  let dbo = db.db('database');

  dbo.call(`fetchMissingDates('abcd')`, (error, result) => {});
});
```

The only thing that I could think of is using `$where` to check whether current `_id` is within the list of `_id`s returned by the function, but I'm afraid this would be an unnecessary waste of resources since it already gives me what I'm looking for.